# Show updating information without user interaction with curses

Tags: ruby, curses

Task is to print to the screen some continuously changing information without user input for some period of time using curses lib.

Following code illustrates idea.

```
require 'curses'
include Curses

str = String.new

init_screen()
  5.times do |val|
  str << "This is the #{val} time we've done something.\n"
  addstr(str)
  getstr
  sleep 1
  clear
end

close_screen
```

After pressing Enter 4th times out put is:

```
This is the 0 time we've done something.
This is the 1 time we've done something.
This is the 2 time we've done something.
This is the 3 time we've done something.
This is the 4 time we've done something.
```

But when i remove 'getstr', which i don't need, there is nothing prints out.

I would be greatful for advice or clue how to deal with curses in such situation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call refresh, to update the screen content:

```
init_screen()
  5.times do |val|
  str << "This is the #{val} time we've done something.\n"
  addstr(str)
  refresh
  sleep 1
  clear
end
```